# Creating an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to programming and i have been learning C the past few months.

I am working on a program that stores pairs of integers in an array. The program prompts the user to enter the number of pairs to be entered, and then I need to allocate storage for the array and then the user enters the pairs line by line to be stored in the array. The program needs to access these pairs to perform operations on later.

I am having trouble trying to set this up. How can I create this kind of data set, in which each member contains a pair of integers, without knowing the initial size of the array?

Comment: Might be helpful: http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation.

Comment: "the program prompts the user to enter the number of pairs" and "without knowing the initial size of the array" are contradictory. Once the user enters the number of pairs you then know the size of the array to allocate.

Comment: No it's not. I have to initialize the array before I prompt the user.

Comment: Why would that be the case? Is that an actual requirement specified by the problem statement or you just think that is needed? Any sensible and practical implementation would do the allocation after getting the number of pairs. If you don't know the number of pairs then it is impossible to allocate an array that will be sure to fit that. You could guess but then would still need to do another allocation if the guess is wrong.

Comment: It was my understanding that in C you had to declare all variables before calling any functions.

Comment: @AdamWest You can declare a pointer variable and allocate it after.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for dynamic array in C. The type that you need is a pointer to your pairs that will be allocated regarding the user choice.

I have written a simple sample code from your description, to help you to understand dynamic allocations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct MyPair
{
    int first;
    int second;
};

int main()
{
    int nPairCount=0;
    struct MyPair *pPairs = NULL;

    // .... prompt from the user
    // let's say we have a nPairCount>0
    // We allocate a memory space in the heap that will be able to store
    // nPairCount pairs contiguously. 
    pPairs = malloc(nPairCount*sizeof(struct MyPair));
    if(pPairs == NULL)
    {
        // LOG ERROR, THERE IS NOT ENOUGH MEMORY TO ALLOCATE YOUR PAIRS
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i= 0; i<nPairCount; ++i)
    {
        // you can access the i-th pair in memory thanks to [] operator
        // Fill the currentPair
        // pPairs[i].first = ... ;
        // pPairs[i].second= ... ;

    }

    // Do your process

    // Do not forget to free your pairs from memory
    free(pPairs);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Casting the result of malloc is not needed (or recommended).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, this cast comes from my c++ habits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a bucket function available in c. But you could create an array that has the number of elements entered by the user.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int a,i;
printf("Enter the number of pairs: ");
scanf("%d",&a);

double b[a*2];\\note that a is number of pairs, so 2a will make it elements
printf("Enter the numbers: \n");
for(i=0;i<(2*a-1);i=i+2)
{
    scanf("%lf %lf",&b[i],&b[i+1]);
}
printf("The pairs entered by you are:\n ");
for(i=0;i<(2*a-1);i=i+2)
{
    printf("%lf and %lf\n ",b[i],b[i+1]);
}


return 0;
}
```

All I have done is take up 2 elements at a time and assign them consecutive arrays and then print them pairwise.

Sample output:
Enter the number of pairs: 3

Enter the numbers:

12 14

45 456

321 568

The pairs entered by you are:

12.000000 and 14.000000

45.000000 and 456.000000

321.000000 and 568.000000